# Error: Customer ID is invalid - WooCommerce Rest Api - PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

When trying to create an order via the WooCommerce Rest Api, I get this error message: **Error: Customer ID is invalid.**

However the Customer ID is in the request:

```
$data = '{
          "order": {
            "status": "processing",
            "customer_id": 36,
            "currency": "",
            "billing_address": {
              "first_name": "",
              "last_name": "",
              "company": "",
              "address_1": "",
              "address_2": "",
              "city": "",
              "state": "",
              "postcode": "",
              "country": "",
              "email": "",
              "phone": ""
            },
            "shipping_address": {
              "first_name": "",
              "last_name": "",
              "company": "",
              "address_1": "",
              "address_2": "",
              "city": "",
              "state": "",
              "postcode": "",
              "country": ""
            },
            "line_items": [
              {
                "id": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "product_id": 271,
              },
              {
                "id": null,
                "quantity": 3,
                "product_id": 273,
              }
            ],
          }
        }';
```

Full code

```
    $client = new WC_API_Client( 'http://mywebsite.com', 'key', 'secret', $options );       
    $data = '{
      "order": {
        "status": "processing",
        "customer_id": 36,
        "currency": "",
        "billing_address": {
          "first_name": "",
          "last_name": "",
          "company": "",
          "address_1": "",
          "address_2": "",
          "city": "",
          "state": "",
          "postcode": "",
          "country": "",
          "email": "",
          "phone": ""
        },
        "shipping_address": {
          "first_name": "",
          "last_name": "",
          "company": "",
          "address_1": "",
          "address_2": "",
          "city": "",
          "state": "",
          "postcode": "",
          "country": ""
        },
        "line_items": [
          {
            "id": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "product_id": 271,
          },
          {
            "id": null,
            "quantity": 3,
            "product_id": 273,
          }
        ],
      }
    }';

$client->orders->create($data);

} catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) {

    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    //echo $e->getCode() . PHP_EOL;

    if ( $e instanceof WC_API_Client_HTTP_Exception ) {

        print_r( $e->get_request() );
        //print_r( $e->get_response() );
    }
}
```

I did check this post:
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/8561

And I can confirm that none of the .htacess files have this problem. Or even look like it.

Comment: Please see my answer on the following thread , you are using an invalid data structure. `"status": "processing"` should be `"status" => "processing"` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650739/woocommerce-create-order-with-hebrew-text-using-the-api-retuns-an-error

Comment: Awesome, that did it. Thanks.

Comment: If you make an answer with the link to that other question I'll mark it as the answer for this one.

Thanks again.

Comment: have done so. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link only answers are not accepted on SO :) so I'll provide some explanation. You are using an invalid data structure, please see my answer on the following thread : [Woocommerce create order with hebrew text using the api retuns an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32650739/woocommerce-create-order-with-hebrew-text-using-the-api-retuns-an-error)

Correct data structure is given below for your reference. It may be missing some keys, for a full list of key/value pairs that you can pass to the API,  see the documentation here : http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-an-order

```
$p = $client->orders->create( 
        array (
            'payment_details' => array( 
                "method_id" => "bacs",
                "method_title" => "Direct Bank Transfer",
                "paid" => true
            ),

            'billing_address' => array( 
                "first_name" => "אֱלֹהִ֑ים",
                "last_name" => "Almighty",
                "address_1" => "969 Market",
                "address_2" => "",
                "city" => "San Francisco",
                "state" => "CA",
                "postcode" => "94103",
                "country" => "US",
                "email" => "john.doe@example.com",
                "phone" => "(555) 555-5555" 
            ),

            'shipping_address' => array( 
                "first_name" => "אֱלֹהִ֑ים",
                "last_name" => "Almighty",
                "address_1" => "969 Market",
                "address_2" => "",
                "city" => "San Francisco",
                "state" => "CA",
                "postcode" => "94103",
                "country" => "US"
            ),

            'line_items' => array(
                array( 
                    'product_id' => 579,
                    'quantity' => 2                     
                )               
            ),

            'shippling_lines' => array(
                array(
                    'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
                    'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
                    'total' => 10                   
                )               
            ),


   ));
```